# git go forward if I don't know hash of commit

Tags: git

I have some trouble with git. I have a branch local and on server. I made some important commits on local pc and then pull from server branch. and this action revert me to the old revision. And I don't know how to go forward again. git log show only current head and previous revisions. can I revert my head forward to my newest commit?

Comment: You probably done something wrong. `git reflog` can show recently changes of branches. Run it and find your last commit (it's hash). Then checkout it like `git checkout HASH -b branch_name`

Comment: thanks, rutsy!
I already revert my head (saw needed hash in terminal history). I find trouble: "HEAD detached at 5cff6e7". And when I did checkout on another branch it cleared my commits. What does mean HEAD deteched, how did I do that? It means that I been on no branch??

Comment: Did you run `git status`? One reason for that to happen during a `git pull` is that you run into a merge conflict and git stops waiting for you to resolve it and commit the resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HEAD of your repo is a special reference that points to the commit that your working directory is at right now. A 'detached HEAD' means that the HEAD is not pointing a the top of a branch, rather it is pointing to some commit in the past. This is fine for viewing code from the past but you don't want to commit onto this. Before committing you want to be at the top of a branch, not somewhere in the middle.

None of your commits should be actually deleted. You should be able to see all commits by running

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

This will display a fairly easy to read representation of your commits as well as showing where different references are pointed. Many people have this command aliased as `git tree` (even though it is not a tree it is a directed acyclic graph, but whatever...)

It will also show the hash of each commit along with the commit message. Find the commit hash that you want and run

```
git reset --hard <commithash>
```

Note that this will change your working directory to being exactly as it is in *commithash* which will delete any unsaved work. You can do a soft reset and the current working directory is preserved.

```
git reset --soft <commithash>
```

Alternatively, you can use `reflog`. Reflog is basically a history of how the HEAD has changed. Running

```
git reflog
```

will show you a history of everywhere that the HEAD has pointed to since you cloned the repo. You can make the HEAD point somewhere it used to by using the HEAD@{n} naming system. So if you see that the action you want to return to is

```
HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from development to mainline
```

you can run

```
git checkout HEAD@{6}
```

and you'll be fine. Personally, I don't recommend this unless you know what you're doing because its very easy to end up in a detached HEAD state from this.